# Loop with data dependency

Tags: c, openmp

I'm learning how to parallelize code in C using OpenMP, using `#pragma omp parallel for` and reductions.

When there's no data dependencies it's cool, but I'm stuck with this piece of code:

```
for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    fx(Q, ffx, m, n, i);
    for (j = 1; j < m; j++)
        nFx[k][j] = 0.5 * ((ffx[k][j-1] + ffx[k][j]) - dx/dt * (Q(k, j, i) - Q(k, j-1, i)));
    for (j = 1; j < m-1; j++)
        Q(k, j, i) = Q(k, j, i) - dt/dx * ((nFx[k][j+1] - nFx[k][j]));     
}
```

I need to change the expression on the fourth line (same in the seventh) so there's no data dependency and put a `#pragma omp for` but I can't see it.

If there's anyone who can help I'd be so appreciated.

Comment: I see no data dependencies. In the first loop there are no reads from nFx, so there can be no loop carried dependencies, and in the second, Q(k,i,j) is updated, but without referring to any other element of Q, so there are no dependencies there.  So it seems reasonable to go parallel before the first j loop, and tag each loop with omp for. The implicit barrier after the first loop will ensure that all nFx updates in the first loop have occurred before any nFx reads in the second can occur.

Comment: what is k here? constant with respect to i and j? also why the second and third loop having loop variable as j? Can they be within single j loop?